# C#/.NET Multi-threaded Task, Playing multiple WAV files with WindowsMediaPlay ERROR

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, genetic-algorithm, multitasking

Hi guys I'm working on a species counterpoint generator using Genetic Algorithms, I've used windows media play to play individual melody but I use a multithreaded solution for playing 2 melodies at same time (PlayMelodies()) but I get this error message (below) any help would be realy appreciated

EDIT: It play 4 notes from both melodies together and then it crashes.

> {"The message filter indicated that the application is busy.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A
>   (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))"}  System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

```
    static Note[] cantus1;
    static Note[] counter1;

    internal void PlayMelody(Note[] melody)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < melody.Length; i++)
        {
            string s = "H:\\Notes\\" + melody[i].NoteName + ".wav";
            WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wmp = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
            wmp.URL = s;
            try
            {
                wmp.controls.play();
            }
            catch (COMException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                wmp.controls.play();
            }

            // Do something.
            for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 100; i2++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }

            wmp.controls.stop();

            /*SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(s);
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            player.Play();
            stopwatch.Start();

            // Do something.
            for(int i2 = 0; i2 < 1000 ; i2++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }

            // Stop timing.
            stopwatch.Stop();
            player.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine(melody[i].NoteName + "\tTime elapsed: {0}", stopwatch.Elapsed);*/

        }
    }

    internal void PlayMelodies(Note[] cantus, Note[] counter)
    {
        cantus1 = cantus;
        counter1 = counter;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(PlayCF);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(PlayCP);
    }

    private void PlayCF()
    {
        PlayMelody(cantus1);
    }

    private void PlayCP()
    {
        PlayMelody(counter1);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: My guess would be that windows media player can't play two files at the same time. If you want to mix (or generally work with) audio in windows, you are probably better off using Mark Heath's NAudio. Here's an example: http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/mixing-and-looping-with-naudio.html

Comment: @ Sorry just added an edit, so it does work it plays 4 notes from each melody simultaneously but when it goes to play the 5th (out of 11) it outputs this error.